# each.cons not returning anything

Tags: ruby

The first section of my win_vertical method pushes each element into a new array. I have put p's to see what is going on for output. When I run the code the @column array gets filled as it should yet nothing happens after each_cons, no errors and doesn't print anything.

```
class Board
    attr_accessor :board
    def initialize 
        @board = Array.new(6){Array.new(7," ")}
    end 


  def win_vertical
    @board.each do |element|
        @column = Array.new
        @column <<  element[2]
        p @column
        @column.each_cons(4) do |cons|
            p cons
            if cons == [["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]
                puts "\n You win!"
                return true
            end
        end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: `each_cons` doesn't return values in single-element arrays, so maybe your expectation is incorrect? I feel that if you provided a minimal, verifiable example you would have found the problem.

Comment: column ends up being an array full of single element arrays. Still wouldn't work? @column isn't a single element array.

Comment: What's the output of `p cons`?

Comment: Nothing, that's why I'm having a tough time. No output to work with..no error either, code still runs.

Comment: What's the output of `p @column`?

Comment: https://repl.it/L5MO just click run

Answer (score 1):

I had created the array after the @board.each iteration had started which made a new array with every iteration. Creating the new array before iterating allowed each_cons to function properly since it will not output on a single element array.

```
 def win_vertical
    @column = Array.new
    @board.each do |element|
        @column <<  element[2]
        p @column
        @column.each_cons(4) do |cons|
            p cons
            if cons == [["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]
                puts "\n You win!"
                return true
            end
        end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.